# dconf and gettings show different results

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dconf, gsettings

My 18.04 laptop is not auto suspending on AC, although I can manually suspend it from the logout dialog, so there is no hardware issue. 
For testing purposes, I have tried a 60 second suspend. 
I am trying to understand why it is not working. I can't find logs.

Also, I found two different values for the suspend delay setting. One of them is 60 seconds, and one is 10800 seconds. The second one is puzzling me.

```
dconf dump / | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"
```

gives

```
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=10800
sleep-display-battery=1800
lid-close-battery-action='suspend'
lid-close-ac-action='suspend'
sleep-display-ac=1800
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=1800
power-button-action='suspend'
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=60
sleep-inactive-ac-type='suspend'
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=900
```

but this shows different settings.

```
tim@moncrief:/etc/dconf/profile$ gsettings list-recursively | grep inactive
ca.desrt.dconf-editor.Settings saved-view '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 60
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
tim@moncrief:/etc/dconf/profile$
```

Comment: Hi - I use gsettings too, not dconf - First please confirm that you tested suspend with `systemctl suspend` - Then See if power management is active with `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active` should be set to `true`

Comment: If you run `dconf watch /` and then toggle settings in GUI, you'll see what actual schemas are being changed. Otherwise, good question.  My best guess is that some settings are system-wide, while others may be user-specific, but it's just a guess

Comment: You are correct ... I had this key too /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon